# Why does event log events crash powershell?

Tags: event-handling, event-log

this will run and work fine for a few minutes but then it crashes powershell and I can't figure out why.

```
    $job = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject ($log = [system.diagnostics.eventlog]"Security") -eventname EntryWritten -SourceIdentifier 'logger'-action {if ($event.sourceeventargs.entry.eventID -eq 4624) {$event.sourceEventargs.entry.replacementstrings[5] >> e:\text\text.txt}}
```

it should just dump out User IDs to a txt file as the events are created. Which it does for a few min.

I was collecting the logs and then filtering through them for the same thing but it was taking about an hour and 15 min to go through and hours worth of logs. Was hopping to just collect it as it came in.

the only thing I can think of is that they come in faster than PS can handle them or something with writing to the file.

So I changed it so that it just outputs to host but it still crashes so it's not writing to the file that's doing it.

Is there a limit on how many events it can handle in 1 minute?

Edit: so it apparently runs fine in ISE but not a normal powershell window. Any idea would be helpful.

Edit: it still crashed in ISE. just happened to run for a few hours first.

Comment: Is there an actual error, or does PS go unresponsive?

Comment: It closes. no error(that I can find). just closes the PS window.